# pmrep: [REP_55035] Not deploying DG - Dependent Session in source repository is required to deploy Workflow

Tags: deployment, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In our current Project we are using Deployment Groups to migrate the code from DEV to TEST/PROD servers. We use Repository Manager to Create DG/Deploy the Code. As to reduce the effort on this, we want to perform this using PMREP command.

**Issue:**

I am deploying a DG which has 8 sessions which belong to a single Workflow ( lets call is wkf_ABC. This workflow contains 20 Sessions in TEST Env). Out of this 8 sessions , one session is new one and rest of the 8 sessions are ones which exist in ENV as well. I have added

a)8 sessions with all dependencies and 
b) Workflow with no dependencies

I am deploying it using two methods, one of them is using Repository Manger and other one is using PMREP command.
1) When using Repository Manger, I am able to deploy the DG to TEST env succesfully ( provided I compare the folders - checking the CHECK BOX in Select Compare Folders Option while Deploying the DG - or else its failing with the Error as shown in the screenshot)
2) When using the pmrep deploydeploymentgroup command with the same DG, the DG is not getting deployed showing the below error.
Error: Dependent Session s_123 (id=xxxx) in source repository is required to deploy Workflow wkf_ABC, it is not available in the target repository and is not part of the deployment group.
Copy failed, rolling back changes...
Please help me if I am missing something

**More Inputs :**

1) s_123 is not part of 8 sessions which are getting deployed and the session s_123 is already in Target repository ( ENV)
2) The Deployment config files which we have used with pmrep command and the one which I have used have same set of attributes.
3) I have seen there are some similar issues when using pmrep command like Object mismatch etc. other than that everything looks good.

**Systematic Deployment ( Repository Manager)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DEPLOYPARAMS SYSTEM "depcntl.dtd">
<DEPLOYPARAMS DEFAULTSERVERNAME = "" COPYPROGRAMINFO = "YES" COPYMAPVARPERVALS = "YES" COPYWFLOWVARPERVALS = "NO" COPYWFLOWSESSLOGS = "NO" COPYDEPENDENCY = "YES" LATESTVERSIONONLY = "NO" RETAINGENERATEDVAL = "YES" RETAINSERVERNETVALS = "YES" RETAINMAPVARPERVALS = "NO">
<DEPLOYGROUP>
<APPLYLABEL SOURCELABELNAME = "" SOURCEMOVELABEL = "NO" TARGETLABELNAME = "" TARGETMOVELABEL = "NO"/>
</DEPLOYGROUP>
</DEPLOYPARAMS>
```

**Deployment Configurant file passed along with pmrep command**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DEPLOYPARAMS    SYSTEM "/dev1/usr/local/informatica/9.1.0/server/bin/depcntl.dtd">
<DEPLOYPARAMS DEFAULTSERVERNAME = "" COPYPROGRAMINFO = "YES" COPYMAPVARPERVALS = "YES" COPYWFLOWVARPERVALS = "NO" COPYWFLOWSESSLOGS = "NO" COPYDEPENDENCY = "YES" LATESTVERSIONONLY = "NO" RETAINGENERATEDVAL = "YES" RETAINSERVERNETVALS = "YES" RETAINMAPVARPERVALS = "NO">
<DEPLOYGROUP CLEARSRCDEPLOYGROUP="NO">
<OVERRIDEFOLDER SOURCEFOLDERNAME = "B_EDW_ODS_ICDS" SOURCEFOLDERTYPE = "LOCAL" TARGETFOLDERNAME = "B_EDW_ODS_ICDS" TARGETFOLDERTYPE = "LOCAL" MODIFIEDMANUALLY = "YES"/>
.
.
.(extra lines for other folders)
<APPLYLABEL SOURCELABELNAME = "" SOURCEMOVELABEL = "NO" TARGETLABELNAME = "" TARGETMOVELABEL = "NO"/>
</DEPLOYGROUP>
</DEPLOYPARAMS>
```

**Informatica(r) PMREP, version [9.1.0 HotFix6], build [496.0111], LINUX 64-bit**

Comment: The problems seems to be, that you added the workflow to your deployment group. Inside the workflow in ENV, there are 20 sessions. But not all of these 20 sessions exist in PROD and or not all in your deployment group. I would always select workflows with ALL dependencies when using deployment groups. You'll save yourself a lot of troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Socken23. I cannot go ahead with adding Workflow with ALL Dependencies as I have some extra sessions ( in Source REPO) which are not yet allowed to move into Target REPO. And you can see that, we are successfully deploying with Repo DG. But not with the one created using PMREP. Please help me with your other inputs

Comment: @RakeshKondaparthy although i think its most likely due to the design of your workflow. But did you figured out the cause and the fix to this interesting issue?